# ElasticSearch library in Java not able to find AggregationBuilders.sum method

Tags: java, maven, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am trying to use AggregationBuilders api of ElasticSearch in java to find sum aggregations.But on using the service which uses this (AggregationBuilders.sum()) method ,it give s following error:

`java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:org.elasticsearch.search.aggregations.;`

This is my pom.xml file

````
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Elasticsearch dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
            <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
            <version>7.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.elasticsearch.client/elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
            <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client</artifactId>
            <version>7.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.elasticsearch.plugin/transport-netty4-client -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch.plugin</groupId>
            <artifactId>transport-netty4-client</artifactId>
            <version>7.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0.M1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-openfeign-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0.M2</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <version>2.1.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>```
````

So far i have tried by cleaning .m2 and running clean install again but still this error is coming.
Any help would be appreciated:

PS : After altering pom i am able to stop elasticsearch 6.5 from installing but 6.4.3 is still installing.I want only 7.2 version.Any idea how to find the dependency which is causing other versions to install

new Pom of es module

```
        <!-- Elasticsearch dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
            <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
            <version>7.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.elasticsearch.client/elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
            <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client</artifactId>
            <version>7.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.elasticsearch.plugin/transport-netty4-client -->
        <!--<dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch.plugin</groupId>
            <artifactId>transport-netty4-client</artifactId>
            <version>7.2.0</version>
        </dependency>-->

       <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-openfeign-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0.M2</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>-->
     

    </dependencies>
```

This is the pom of aggregator project:

````
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.dummy.proj</groupId>
    <artifactId>dummy-proj</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <modules>
        <module>es</module>
        <module>ms</module>
    </modules>

    <properties>
        <!-- These Properties are common for all spring R&D for maven build-->
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
       
        <common.lang.version>2.4</common.lang.version>
        <dummy.version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</dummy.version>
        <lombok.version>1.16.18</lombok.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
       
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

<!--

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
-->


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>```
````

Comment: Can you run `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=org.elasticsearch` and see if you have several conflicting versions of Elasticsearch. It's often the case when using Spring Boot and Spring Data in addition to importing your own version of ES.

Comment: yeah it is given something like this:[INFO] +- org.elasticsearch.client:elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client:jar:7.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- (org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch:jar:7.2.0:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] \- org.springframework.data:spring-data-elasticsearch:jar:3.2.0.M1:compile
[INFO]    \- org.elasticsearch.client:transport:jar:6.5.0:compile
[INFO]       \- (org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch:jar:6.5.0:compile - omitted for conflict with 7.2.0)

Comment: So there you go, you have a mix of ES 6.5.0 (imported by Spring Boot/Data ES) and 7.2.0 (imported manually)... If you fix that, you're good to go.

Comment: I am able to prevent ES 6.5 but 6.4.3 is still installing .. any idea how to check for dependency which is causing install of es 6.4.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Data Elasticsearch 3.2 does not work with Elasticsearch 7; 3.2.0.GA uses Elasticsearch 6.8.

Support and adaption for Easticsearch 7 is in the now current master branch that will become version 4 later

Comment: I changed my ElasticSearch versions to 6.8 in pom and it worked!!!Thanks a lot..