# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/elasticsearch/search/aggregations/metrics/max/MaxAggregationBuilder

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I'm upgrading my application from spring-boot 2.0 to 2.3 then I found this error regarding elastic search

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/elasticsearch/search/aggregations/metrics/max/MaxAggregationBuilder
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2671) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2020) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindConstructorProvider.findConstructorBindingAnnotatedConstructor(ConfigurationPropertiesBindConstructorProvider.java:62) ~[spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindConstructorProvider.getBindConstructor(ConfigurationPropertiesBindConstructorProvider.java:48) ~[spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBean$BindMethod.forType(ConfigurationPropertiesBean.java:311) ~[spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBeanDefinitionValidator.validate(ConfigurationPropertiesBeanDefinitionValidator.java:63) ~[spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBeanDefinitionValidator.postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurationPropertiesBeanDefinitionValidator.java:45) ~[spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:291) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:175) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:706) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:532) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:143) ~[spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758) [spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750) [spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237) [spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) [spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at com.lms.firebaseNotification.FireBaseNotification.main(FireBaseNotification.java:22) [classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49) [app.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:109) [app.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58) [app.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88) [app.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.elasticsearch.search.aggregations.metrics.max.MaxAggregationBuilder
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:129) ~[app.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    ... 28 common frames omitted
```

When I searched online I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58266367/elasticsearch-library-in-java-not-able-to-find-aggregationbuilders-sum-method) but my case is a little different I don't use `MaxAggregationBuilder` explicitly anywhere in my code so it is probably hidden in abstractions somewhere.

**Note:** I didn't specifiy `spring-data-elasticserch`'s version explicitly, I know it should be 4.x, but I left that to the spring boot parent, so I don't think it is a dependency problem but I don't know.

Comment: You are not updating Spring, but Spring Boot.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Data Elasticsearch does not build any aggregation in it's code by itself, so this must be referenced somewhere else when creating a `NativeSearchQuery` - that's the only way to build an aggregation request in Spring Data Elasticsearch. Do you include other libraries that might create some requests?
The requested class btw is in the package `org.elasticsearch.search.aggregations.metrics`.

Spring Boot 2.0 was using Spring Data Elasticsearch 3.0.x and Elasticsearch 5.5.0 whereas Spring Boot 2.3 uses Spring Data Elasticsearch 4.0.x and Elasticsearch 7.6. I suppose that the package changed in Elasticsearch during 5.5 and 7.6.

Comment: Thanks @P.J.Meisch, but why the error was a runtime error instead of compile-time or a deprecation warning I'm using `NativeSearchQuery` once to do Wildcard query I don't think this should be related to `MaxAggregationBuilder`

Comment: there must be some code building this query, and this is not in Spring Data Elasticsearch, so you have to find the place where the query is built